# SQL - counting people with same job. Simple code given

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need help counting the number of job types (CLERK, analyst etc). I have written some code but it doesnt return what I want it to. Could anyone suggest whats wrong?
Thanks - Jay

```
SELECT  COUNT(*)
FROM    emp e, emp d
WHERE   e.job = d.job;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a GROUP BY clause to inform MySql what different things you want to count.  In this case, you want to count unique job values:

```
SELECT
    job,
    Count(job)
FROM
    emp e
GROUP BY
    job
```

Demo: http://sqlize.com/lfA2Z9nagw

Answer (score -2):

If all you need is the number of job types in the table, this simple query will do it:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Job) from emp
```

Comment: Based on the accepted answers, this is clearly Not what the op wanted. Also, this question is over 12 years old!